# Best practice for storing Firestore data model

Tags: android, database, security, google-cloud-firestore, data-modeling

When using Firestore and Android, if we want to store the data model in one place, we can store it:

In XML:

```
<string name="collection_users">users</string>
<string name="user_first_name">first</string>
<string name="user_last_name">last</string>
<string name="user_year_birth">born</string>
```

Or directly in Java:

```
public static final String COLLECTION_USERS = "users";
public static final String FIELD_FIRST_NAME = "first";
public static final String FIELD_LAST_NAME = "last";
public static final String FIELD_YEAR_BIRTH = "born";
```

However, in both cases, we expose the entire data model of the DB in the client code, making the job of attackers easier in case they get somehow their hands on the source code of the app. Is there any good practice or suggested approach to minimize the exposure of the structure of the DB in the client code, when using a No-SQL DB such as Firestore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any good practice or suggested approach to minimize the exposure of the structure of the DB when using a No-SQL DB such as Firestore?

Sure it is, use Firestore security rules, so you can secure your database according to your needs. For that, I recommend you read the official documentation regarding [getting started with Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).

> Security rules provide access control and data validation in a simple yet expressive format. To build user-based and role-based access systems that keep your users' data safe, you need to use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) with Cloud Firestore Security Rules.

Since exposing the database structure cannot be prevented, the name of the collections/documents should explicitly exist in your code so you can use them in your references. But this won't be a problem as long as you secure your database correctly. You can move some logic (when possible) server side, will be a good option.

You can also try to store those names in a local database if you want and encrypt them, but in my opinion there is no benefit in doing this. It's up to you to choose if you need some kind of encryption or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Firestore security rules are a must, of course. My question is if there is a way to avoid exposing the data model in the client code

Comment: You need to have the name of the collections/documents explicitly in your code so you can use them in your references. But this won't be a problem as long as you secure your database correctly.

Comment: Even when using correct and well thought security rules, not exposing the data model helps minimizing the probability of data breaches. Also, exposing the data model exposes the back-end solutions of the app and what the app stores, in detail. I take from your answer that there is no (easy) way to do it.

Comment: I didn't said that there is no way, I only said that as long as you use security rules correctly, there won't be a problem. You can try to store those names in a local database if you want and encrypt them, but in my opinion there is no benefit in doing this. It's up to you to choose if you need some kind of encryption or not.

Comment: I know you didn't, that's why I put "easy" before. Encryption is not worth it, I agree. Unfortunately it seems that for not exposing those parts of the data model that one does not want to show or containing more sensitive data, the solution is to move to server-side as much as possible. With SQL databases this is less often a problem for a number of reasons. Anyhow, thanks again for your answers.

Comment: Yes, you can move some logic (when possible) server side, it's a good option. And you're very welcome, cheers!

Comment: @AlexMamo Would you mind editing some of you comments into your answer? Since the question was about exposing the database structure (which cannot be prevented), I feel that would make it better fit with the question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I always do, but I don't think that "Using Firestore security rules"  or "reading the official documentation regarding getting started with Cloud Firestore Security Rules" regards exposing the database structure. AlexMamo If you edit the answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: @user1823280 Just edited my answer accordingly. Thanks.